# this error is getting when i am trying to load light box in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

[link text](http://boxyourtvtrial.com/cakephp-hDemo/js/ajax.js)

Hi,
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.statusText]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: http://boxyourtvtrial.com/cakephp-hDemo/js/ajax.js :: anonymous :: line 156" data: no]

please help....

thanks

Comment: The page that you are getting the error on would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in an `alert(self.xmlhttp.statusText);` to see what it is getting. I don't know what `statusText` is or where it is coming from as you haven't given us that bit of code.

To be honest, though, this has nothing (at the moment) to do with Cakephp, the error looks more like a system config error (like you're maybe not loading a library), and you should really try writing that sort of javascript yourself so that you can understand what is going on.